# onChange event for select attribute

Tags: html, asp.net

is there a way to do onChange event for `<selec>` in asp.net?

i have tried

```
protected void Status_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

EDIT:
the problem:

code behind:

```
protected void Status_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Label1.Text = "ok";
}
```

html:

```
<form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <select id="Status" name="Status" class="regis" style="width:170px" onselectedindexchanged="Status_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <option value="0">1</option>
        <option value="1">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

why doesnt it work?
tnx for the help :D

Comment: Its Selected Index changed event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlselect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlselect_Changed">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

In Code Behind

```
protected void ddlselect_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add `runat="server"` like following:

```
 <select id="Status" name="Status" class="regis" style="width:170px" onselectedindexchanged="Status_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 <select id="Status" name="Status" class="regis" style="width:170px" onselectedindexchanged="Status_SelectedIndexChanged">
<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
</select>
```

by

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Status" runat="server" Width="200px" onselectedindexchanged="Status_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <asp:ListItem Value="0">1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```